# Attachments are hidden in Outlook new Plain Text message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments

Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.6326.1010) 64-bit, as part of Office 365 subscription

Since about a month attachments in a new Plain Text message do not show up.
The attachments are there since if I convert the message to HTML, the attachments show up.
But the Attachments line in Plain Text mode is just missing.
See two screenshots:

- Hidden in plain text email

[image: outlook-attachment-missing-in-plain-text.png]

- Present in HTML email

[image: outlook-attachment-present-in-html.png]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has acknowledged the bug as of 12/29/15, but as of today (1/6/16), they are still "researching this problem":

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3132071